# Command Prompt In a Website

Tags: javascript, html

Just learning javascript, and I'm trying to make a DND Starting Kit as a little project, is it possible to make a text box or a command prompt that can use the functions and variables that I have in my code? I'm just trying to put it in the bottom-left corner, so the user can type what he wants to do command/function wise.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: What line of code could I use?

Comment: eval, but thats nasty and dangerous :p

Comment: I suppose you want to `eval` what the user typed into the box.

Comment: And how would I make said text box?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can with **eval** but it is really slow and may cause a lot of problems.

You should use with try&catch like this

```
    var input = document.getElementById("inputElement").value;

    try{
    //evaluate string as code
    eval(input);
    }catch(e){
    //if something goes wrong
  }
```

And for the part "How to make said textbox" there is **textarea** element

```
<textarea id="inputElement" rows="5" cols="100">
<!--User will put input here-->
</textarea>
```

### EDIT:

---

Ok, so you asked me for an example how you could make some sort of console.

**Here's an example:**

```js
var consoleElement = document.getElementById("myConsole");
var inputElement = document.getElementById("userInput");
var buttonElement = document.getElementById("enter");
inputElement.onkeypress = keyPressed;
buttonElement.onclick = enter;

var myConsole = {
  consoleElement: consoleElement,
  write: function(input) {
    this.consoleElement.innerHTML += input;
  },
  writeln: function(input) {
    this.consoleElement.innerHTML += "</br>" + input;
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.consoleElement.innerHTML = "";
  }
}

function enter() {
  var inputString = inputElement.value;
  var str = inputString.substring(inputString.indexOf(' '));
  switch(true){
  case inputString.startsWith("clear"):
  myConsole.clear();
  break;
  case (inputString.startsWith("write") && !inputString.startsWith("writeln")):
  myConsole.write(str);
  break;
  case inputString.startsWith("writeln"):
  myConsole.writeln(str);
  break;
  default:
  myConsole.writeln(inputString.split(" ")[0] + " isn't recognized command");
  }
  inputElement.value = "";
}

function keyPressed(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
  enter();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
}

#myConsole {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

#userInput {
  width: 400px;
}

#enter {
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="myConsole">Welcome to the best console ever!</div>
  <input type="text" id="userInput" />
  <button id="enter">ENTER</button>
</div>
```

It's really buggy, but I just made to show you an example of a console you could make.
you have 3 commands avaiable at the time : **clear, write, writeln** play around with it.
Try to understand how it works and you can try to fix that if you writeln too many times text gets out of box!
CHEERS!

Comment: what would the e be in catch()?

Comment: the `e` in the catch would be an error that would get caught if something went wrong, right there in `catch` you can for example alert user that this input is not correct syntax. You can also log the error to console like so: `console.log(e);`

Comment: Also in that text box, if this makes any sense, I want it to be exactly like a command prompt, with me typing into one line, and when I click enter, it goes into the textbox so I can do a function to roll a dice for example, so i say rollDice (20), and it appears like, You've rolled a D20 and have rolled a 17.

Comment: uhm, that might be more tricky, I'd suggest you to have a div of some sort where you would show the output of the said 'console'. And keep user input in one element, I think that `<input type="text" />` would be even better than **textarea** element

Comment: I can edit my answer and give you a simple snippet if you want

Comment: That'd be great, I'm also working on this through midnight, 2:12 right now here, EST I think

Comment: @KevinHuynh If you're going to be accepting user input that way and `eval`-ing it, make sure you check the input first and "sanitize" it to remove things that could possibly cause code to run, such as `<` and `>` symbols.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all of the help guys.

Comment: It took me a while, but there you go, tell me if it works haha!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can. You need to have a textarea and use the javascript "eval" function:

```js
function command(){
    let cmds = document.getElementById('txtCommands').value;
    console.log(cmds);
    eval(cmds);
}
```

```html
<textarea col="3" id="txtCommands" name="txtCommands">
alert(1)
</textarea>

<br/>

<button type="button" onclick="command()">Apply</button>
```

Comment: The text area isn't working out with the alert, do I need the function for it to work or?

Comment: You can type whatever function you want and run it.